# How can I add runtime images to Reference Image Library in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime, ar-foundation

I'm using the version 2020.3.20f1 of Unity and I want to create an AR app. In my app the Reference Image Library changes runtime by adding some images contained in a project's folder.

This is my code:
`

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class RuntimeImageLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ARTrackedImageManager trackedImageManager;
    public string imagesFolderName = "RuntimeImages";

    private void Start()
    {
        // Get the runtime reference image library
        var referenceLibrary = trackedImageManager.referenceLibrary;

        // Load images from the specified folder
        var imagesFolder = $"{Application.dataPath}/{imagesFolderName}";
        var imageFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(imagesFolder);

        foreach (var file in imageFiles)
        {
            // Load the image and add it to the reference library
            var imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            var texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
            texture.LoadImage(imageData);

            var imageGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            var guidBytes = imageGuid.ToByteArray();
            var serializableGuid = new UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.SerializableGuid(
                BitConverter.ToUInt64(guidBytes, 8),
                BitConverter.ToUInt64(guidBytes, 0)
            );
            var runtimeImage = new XRReferenceImage(
                serializableGuid,
                serializableGuid,
                new Vector2(texture.width, texture.height) / 1000f, // Replace with the actual size of your image
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                texture
            );

            
            ((XRReferenceImageLibrary)referenceLibrary).Add(runtimeImage);
        }
    }
```

But this generate this error:

> Assets/RuntimeImageLoader.cs(43,57): error CS1061:
> 'XRReferenceImageLibrary' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and
> no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of
> type 'XRReferenceImageLibrary' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

I also tried `referenceLibrary.Add(runtimeImage` but it doesn't work.

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Unity documentation, `XRReferenceImageLibrary` is an immutable collection at runtime.  That means you can not change the data.

From the documentation ([here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arsubsystems@4.2/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRReferenceImageLibrary.html)):

> Image libraries are immutable at runtime. To create and manipulate an
> image library via Editor scripts, see the extension methods in
> XRReferenceImageLibraryExtensions. If you need to mutate the library
> at runtime, see MutableRuntimeReferenceImageLibrary.

It looks like there is a typeyou can modify at runtime, called [MutableRuntimeReferenceImageLibrary](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arsubsystems@4.2/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.MutableRuntimeReferenceImageLibrary.html).  But whether your AR supports it or not is not guaranteed.  I recommend looking at the documentation for those types to determine if your AR supports it and how to retrieve it.